# Swagger2 handling HashMap

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Trying to get the Swagger UI to show a hashmap and have got nowhere

My Bean is in the format

```
public class Foo {

   private Location location;

   @JsonProperty(required = true)
   private HashMap<String, Bar> bars;
}
```

which results in the following model in swagger ui

```
Foo {
   bars (object, optional),
   location (Location, optional)
}
```

Is there a swagger annotation I need to use here? From the other questions it seems that Swagger2 can now handle HashMaps but I couldn't get any defined examples.